# Unit Test WebApi to upload image using Mock

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am starting to write unit tests for all our controllers and seem to be getting the hang of it, but now i am a bit stuck.  I have the following controller method that i would like to write a unit test for but a am a bit lost.  Can someone please help and point me in the right direction.  I am guessing maybe i need to abstract the method slightly, but not sure how.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
    {
        // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            // Validate the uploaded image, by only accepting certain file types and sizes
            var validExtensions = new List<string>
            {
                ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG"
            };

            if (!validExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            else if (httpPostedFile.ContentLength > 2097152)
            {
                // file is over 2mb in size
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // create a new image
            var entity = new Image
            {
                Name = httpPostedFile.FileName,
                Size = httpPostedFile.ContentLength,
                Data = new ImageData
                {
                    Content = new byte[httpPostedFile.ContentLength]   
                }
            };

            await httpPostedFile.InputStream.ReadAsync(entity.Data.Content, 0, httpPostedFile.ContentLength);

            await _service.AddAsync(entity);

            return Created<ImageModel>(Request.RequestUri, Mapper.Map<ImageModel>(entity));
        }
    }

    return BadRequest();

}
```

EDIT:

Sorry i completely forgot to include dependancy injection code.  I am using SimpleInjector.

So i have now added this to it

```
// return current httpContext
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<HttpContext>(() => HttpContext.Current);
```

Which i cannot yet test because i still cannot work out how to mock httpContext.  my controller is now created like so

```
private IImageService _service;
private HttpContext _httpContext;

public ImageController(IImageService service, HttpContext httpContext)
{
    _service = service;
    _httpContext = httpContext;
}
```

And i have changed HttpContext.Current to _httpContext.

But how can i create a mock of HttpContext??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using dependency injection, the best thing you can do to make this method testable is to inject the `HttpContext.Current`, or even the `Request`, as a dependency to your controller.

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public MyController(IMyService service, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _service = service;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync()
    {
        // action method content
    }
}
```

Then update your action method to use `_httpContext` instead of the static `HttpContext.Current`. Doing this will allow you to create a mock `HttpContext` in your test and pass it into your controller, giving you control over it.

From here, set up your mock `HttpContext` to return whatever you need for your test for parts like `_httpContext.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any()` and `var httpPostedFile = _httpContext.Request.Files[0];`.

You will also need to set up your IoC container (Ninject, Autofac, or whatever you're using) to inject the correct instance of `HttpContext`/`Request` into your controller.

This should give you a good place to start, since going into more detail would require knowledge of which mocking framework, IoC container, etc you're using :)

---

#### Update

Mocking `HttpContext` is tricky, but I've had success mocking it directly in the past. The following are some methods I wrote that use [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) to mock `HttpContext` as an `HttpContextBase`, along with mock `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` properties.

```
public static class MockHttpObjectBuilder
{
    public static HttpContextBase GetMockHttpContext()
    {
        return GetMockHttpContext("~/");
    }

    public static HttpContextBase GetMockHttpContext(string url, string httpMethod = "GET")
    {
        var context = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();

        var req = GetMockHttpRequest(url, httpMethod);
        req.RequestContext.Returns(new RequestContext(context, new RouteData()));
        context.Request.Returns(req);

        var res = GetMockHttpResponse();
        context.Response.Returns(res);

        return context;
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase GetMockHttpRequest()
    {
        return GetMockHttpRequest("~/");
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase GetMockHttpRequest(string url, string httpMethod = "GET")
    {
        var req = Substitute.For<HttpRequestBase>();
        req.ApplicationPath.Returns("/");
        req.Headers.Returns(new NameValueCollection {{"X-Cluster-Client-Ip", "1.2.3.4"}});
        req.ServerVariables.Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Returns(url);
        req.HttpMethod.Returns(httpMethod);
        req.Url.Returns(new Uri("example.com/" + url.TrimStart('~')));
        return req;
    }

    public static HttpResponseBase GetMockHttpResponse()
    {
        var res = Substitute.For<HttpResponseBase>();
        res.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => x[0]);
        return res;
    }
}
```

You may not need all of the things I'm mocking here, this was just a copy/paste of some code I wrote a while ago. Also, you may have to play around with using `HttpContext` vs `HttpContextBase` in your signatures. Here are some links that may help:

- http://www.splinter.com.au/httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-vs-httpcontext/
- [Mock HttpContext.Current in Test Init Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have updated my question with dependency injection changes.  Still cannot work out how to mock httpContext?

Comment: @user2736022: I updated with some more information about mocking `HttpContext`

Comment: Thanks this helped.  Although i pass in HttpContextBase into my controller, rather than HttpContext