# Unit test Class in MVC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following class in my project

```
 public class Data
    {
         public void Getdata(){
            var user =  HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

It is showing null reference exception

It works nicely for Controller, but not for class as Class does not have **ControllerContext** . Any help?

Comment: `public class Data()
{
  var user =  HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}`
is it typo?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It is in method

Comment: @KhanhTO i have done it for Controller. I want it for class

Comment: it should be `HttpContext.Current`, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method

Comment: @KhanhTO Controller has ControllerContext  so we can set up fake context. But do i do it for class?

Comment: @Richa: See the answer that Khanh TO linked to. You would create a fake `HttpContext.Current` before accessing your method in a test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could restructure your class a little to test it in a similar way. One way would be to add a constructor that accepts an `HttpContextBase`:

```
public class Data
{
    private HttpContextBase contextBase;

    public Data(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Data() : this(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
    {
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        var user = this.context.User.Identity.Name
    }
}
```

Then you could pass in your mocked `HttpContextBase` during your unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var fake = new GenericIdentity("user");
    var prin = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

    fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(prin);

    var data = new Mock<Data>(fakeHttpContext.Object);

    // Now you can successfully call data.GetData()
}
```