# HttpContext.Current always null when sending request from unit test

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I have `Web Api controller Action method` I am trying to unit test. I have one custom filter which runs before that action controller.

I have question regarding `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` that I am using inside my custom action filter.

It works nicely when I send my http post request from web client.

But, when I send http post request from my unit test than `HttpContext.Current` always complain for `null`

Don't understand where and what is wrong.
Anybody can please explain it?

**Please** note that I have seen answers at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method) but not sure where I need to add that code in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is not the same as calling your api through a web client.

When you are using a web client, you api is running in the context of you web server (IIS, for example) and the web server will provide the system with che "current" `HttpContext`.

If you call you code plain and simple from a unit test method you're not running in the context of a web server, but you're calling it simply as a method of a class. Obviously you can do it, but you need to "**mock**" (of fake, if you want) the current `HttpContext` to simulate you're running in a real web server.

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method) answer for the details on how to do it.

BTW, this is not the case when you run integration tests (means calling the real API throught a web client and just check the input-output results): in that case you are running your real code in a real context and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current` is not set in a self hosted scenario like in your test.

You can however create a wrapper around `HttpContext.Current` and populate it before you run your test. Like this:

```
public static class CurrentHttpContext
{
    public static Func<HttpContextBase> Instance = () => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

And then somewhere in your test where you set up your `HttpSelfHostServer`, you populate the `CurrentHttpContext.Instance`. For example with `FakeItEasy` (https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy):

```
var context = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
CurrentHttpContext.Instance = () => context;
```

Then you can access `CurrentHttpContext.Instance` instead of `HttpContext.Current` in your filters:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var context = CurrentHttpContext.Instance();
        // stuff
    }
}
```