# HttpContext Null through Unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, httpcontext

I have following piece of code to evaluate the IP address

```
 public string getIPAddress()
        {
            string IPAddress = string.Empty;
            String strHostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
            IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
            return IPAddress;


        }
```

Now when I tried to implement unit testing for this method, it always throws error, null reference,

I could not change the actual method just for unit testing, is there any way to handle this...

Thanks

Comment: You may have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method) which shows how to **mock a httpContext**. I think this would be a good solution in your situation!

Answer (score 1):

That is expected because HttpContext is not available in unit tests and unit tests run in their own context. You will need to have a way to mock/provide HttpContext to your unit tests.

Comment: If I am not missing , then It need changes in actual method, which i don't want

Answer (score 1):

if you would not use "HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress" direct - but through a wrapperclass or other mockable class instead, you could then mock the behaviour.

[Here is an Example](http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-mock-httpcontext-for-unit.html)

you should probably mock `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0)` as well, to get your Test independent of this Class too.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mock HTTPContext while unit testing you can use [typemock](http://www.typemock.com) as in the following example regarding you method:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void TestForHttpContext_willReturn123AsIP()
{
    // Arrange
    Program classUnderTest = new Program();
    IPAddress[] a = { new IPAddress(long.Parse("123")), new IPAddress(long.Parse("456")), new IPAddress(long.Parse("789")) };

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress).WillReturn("testIP");
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Dns.GetHostAddresses(" ")).WillReturn(a);

    // Act
    var res = classUnderTest.getIPAddress();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("123.0.0.0", res);
}
```