# Autofac and the HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have a lot of services that require access to the current user.
I set up a **PrincipalProvider** which bound to the current **HttpContext**, I also registered it per request so that once instantiated, it would never lose the context.
It looks like this:

```
public class PrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{

    // Readonly fields
    private readonly HttpContext _current;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PrincipalProvider()
    {
        _current = HttpContext.Current;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current user
    /// </summary>
    public IPrincipal User => _current?.User;
}
```

And I have bound it like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<PrincipalProvider>().As<IPrincipalProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Now, any service that has this injected into it should have the user exposed. The issue I have is simple. If I have a controller set up like this:

```
public OrdersController(IOrderProvider provider)
{
    _provider = provider;
}
```

That **IOrderProvider** has the **IPrincipleProvider** lazily injected into it, so in this case the user is available because the parent service is created on the Controller. The issue is if it isn't injected into the service, but instead used on another service that is injected into it.
For example, I have this controller:

```
public UsersController(IUserProvider provider, IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider encyptionProvider, IPhotoManager photoManager)
{
    _userProvider = provider;
    _encryptionProvider = encyptionProvider;
    _photoManager = photoManager;
}
```

The **IUserProvider** doesn't have the **IPrincipalProvider** injected into it, but it does have another service that does:

```
public TroposSessionRequest(CormarConfig config, IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider encryptionProvider, Lazy<IPrincipalProvider> principalProvider)
{
    _config = config;
    _encryptionProvider = encryptionProvider;
    _principalProvider = principalProvider;
}
```

The problem here, is that when the **TroposSessionRequest** is created, the **HttpContext** is not available and therefor is null.
I was hoping there was a way to instantiate the **IPrincipleProvider** when the context becomes available and then keep it for the entire request.
We can do this for every request as the **PrincipalProvider** is almost always needed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to workaround the problem is to simply access `HttpContext.Current` in your `User` accessor:

```
public IPrincipal User => HttpContext.Current?.User;
```

If you're concerned about testability, you can [mock HttpContext.Current.User relatively easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method/4379540?noredirect=1#comment77357127_4379540).

If you're set on solving it using DI you could abstract `HttpContext` behind a `IHttpContextAccessor` dependency (but since you're still depending on the `HttpContext` type you'd still be in the same boat in terms of testing).

```
public class PrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{

    // Readonly fields
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PrincipalProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current user
    /// </summary>
    public IPrincipal User => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
}
```

Comment: As I see it, your "workaround" isn't a workaround _at all_. It is actually _the_ solution, since you should [prevent having runtime data in the object graph during construction](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Where can I get access to this IHttpContextAccessor? Is this something only available in core? I am not using .net core :(

Comment: I meant that you'd define it yourself.