# How to create unit test with HttpContext for authorization inside a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

This is my codes :

```
public static ApiResponseBase BookActivity(ActivityBookApiRequest request)
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Identity.Name))
            {
                return new ActivityBookApiResponse
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    ErrorCode = "ERAGPR01"
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
```

How to create unit test for that code?

I was created unit test, but still failed because on `HttpContext.Current.User` given error :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Here's my unit test :

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Book_Null_ReturnBadRequest()
        {
            var expectedResult = new ActivityBookApiResponse
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                ErrorCode = "ERAGPR01"
            };
            var actualResult = ActivityLogic.BookActivity(null);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.StatusCode, actualResult.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.StatusCode, actualResult.StatusCode);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is static and can be assigned:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
    );

// User is logged in
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(
    new GenericIdentity("username"),
    new string[0]
    );

// User is logged out
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(
    new GenericIdentity(String.Empty),
    new string[0]
    );
```

Code from [Mock HttpContext.Current in Test Init Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method)