# How to have HttpContext in a Background Process

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7, hangfire

I'm running hangfire background process. Now part of the function being called is using MediaService which also needs HttpContext because when I try to execute `mediaService.Save(media)` it throws an error of

```
 System.ArgumentNullException
 Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpContext

      System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
      Parameter name: httpContext
```

From what I was reading it needs to be a normal http request and not a background process.

How can we fake or fix the httpcontext issue inside my background service?

```
public void saveMedia()
{
        var mediaService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads");

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                string mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File;
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

                IMedia media = mediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
                media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);
                mediaService.Save(media); // HTTPCONTEXT error here
                media = null;
            }

            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please dont repost your questions. You already have a thread open [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598717/use-umbraco-mediaservice-in-hangfire-job)

Comment: @Jawad will delete the other post sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a way to serialize the HttpContext that you are trying to use in your Hangfire background job. HTTP request scope is not passed as argument when you run a method (with HttpContext or most of its component) in Hangfire. Since methods are serialized and then executed outside of the HTTP request scope, you will have to find a different way to fake the HttpContext in your methods.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404479/add-httpcontext-into-hangfire) for an example on how to create a fake HttpContext in your methods that are executed by Hangfire..

[Another post from Hangfire Developer](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/alternative-for-missing-httpcontent/107) on what you can do to get "some" of the properties from HttpContext by deserializing it before the job execution.