# Mock HttpActionContext C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to mock the HttpActioncontext,But nothing seems to work out.
I'm using nunit 2.7.0 framework . Please help.

**My Controller Method:**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] EditAccountRequest editAccountRequest)
    {
        **var username = ActionContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "username");**
        
       ...........
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock HttpContext.Current in Test Init Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method)

Comment: What do you mean by nothing seems to work? Please add details to your question. Also, welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Test]
        public void PutTest()
        {
            EditAccountRequest editAccountRequest = new EditAccountRequest();
            editAccountRequest.Mode = 1;
            HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null), new HttpResponse(null));
            HttpResponseMessage result = accountController.Put(editAccountRequest);
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }

Comment: @SanKrish [edit] that last comment into the original post. We wont be able to fully understand it in the comments.

Comment: @Nkosi Below code I have tried ,But no luck .  HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "tempuri.org", null), new HttpResponse(null));